# GnuPG Automating Sign+Encrypt - passphrase-fd 0 issues on Windows

Tags: encryption, automation, stdin, gnupg, windows-scripting

I am currently writing a batch script to automate signing and encrypting files, on GnuPG version 2.0.30.

Can someone explain why the following will not work on my Windows machine:

```
echo "passphrase"| gpg2 --batch --yes --always-trust --passphrase-fd 0 -es -r "Public key for encryption" "Path of file to encrypt"
```

To my knowledge, this should be piping the output of echo (my passphrase) as the input of --passphrase-fd 0 (0 operating on STDIN handle of course). I can't seem to get this to work, and wasn't sure if it was my code, or if it's just an issue running this on Windows.

Whenever I execute this command, I get

```
 "no default secret key: Bad passphrase"

 "sign+encrypt failed: Bad passphrase"
```

As a workaround, I was able to use redirection operater < and passed the filepath to my passphrase, still using the STDIN handle (0):

```
gpg2 --batch --yes --always-trust --passphrase-fd 0 -es -r "Public key for encryption" "Path of file to encrypt" < "Filepath to passphrase"
```

I realize it's bad practice to store a passphrase in a local file, and may consider removing the signature altogether, but for my own sake, I want to better understand why this won't work using piping (on Windows).

Thanks!

Comment: This might be an issue with newlines or other characters added -- I don't know enough about WIndows' `echo` command to be more specific with this. Anyway, it is probably even worse to provide secrets with `echo` or in parameters on multi user systems and servers, at least on unix machines all other system users can read the command and it might get logged, while you can much better control who is able to read a specific file.

Comment: And the even better solution would be to use `gpg-preset-passphrase` and preset the passphrase in GnuPG's cache to be able to use it. GnuPG 2.1 pretty much enforces this anyway

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Reading over https://superuser.com/questions/1114704/is-there-a-way-to-decrypt-a-file-in-gpg-without-passphrase-poping-up-and-without, it looks like gpg-preset-passphrase is not available for windows, unless I am missing something. When i call gpg-preset-passphrase, it get a "....is not recognized as an internal command..." unless I need to run this from a different directory, or re-configure gpg-agent (if that's possible from Windows). This makes me want to move to Linux for all of this haha.